# append csv to php array

Tags: php, arrays

I can not get this PHP array to return any values for me.  The CSV sheet consists of 10 numbers.  The only output I get is "`array`"

```
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen("fullbox.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}

echo $data[1];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: array is returned as $data[1] is an array try using var_dump() on it

Answer (score 3):

Your code is already correct.

`$data` is  multidimensional array, each element is an array itself.  When you `echo $data[1]` you are asking PHP to write a string representation of a more complex array variable, which PHP handles by outputting `array` instead of its contents.

Instead, `var_dump()` it to see what it contains.

```
var_dump($data);
```

A single value would be accessed via something like :

```
echo $data[1][0];
```

**Edit after comment**:

If the CSV contains only one value per row, access it directly via `$row[0]` when appending to the output array in order to get it as a 1D array:

```
if (($handle = fopen("fullbox.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $data[] = $row[0];
  }
}
// $data is now a 1D array.
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: @Micheal Is there a way to setup the array so it would be one dimensional for ease of use.  Since I have only one set in the csv file.  Thanks

Comment: @Djacksway See addition above.

Comment: @Micheal maybe I am missing something my CSV consists of one column with 10 numbers.  I just want to be able to call whatever number I want by its corresponding position in the array.  I tried your previous code and I dont get it to return anything.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Djacksway O assumed you meant one _row_ with ten numbers. Stay tuned for an update.

Comment: @Djacksway Code changed above.

Comment: @micheal, but how can I call the ten values by themselves. Like ** $data[5];** if I want to use that particular value for another fucntion

Comment: @Djacksway Just like that -- `echo $data[5];` It's a regular 1D array now, and you access it with simple numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

$data[1] is the second element in your $data variable ($data[0] would be the first).

You are getting an array back instead of a value which is why PHP is echoing the word array.

This should work better.

```
$data[0][0]
```

Your $data variable is a multidimensional array and you are only going one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because $data[1] **is** an array of the 10 numbers in the CSV row, so $data is now a multi-dimensional array.  `echo $data[1][0]` will output one of the numbers